# SOAP HEADERS error

Tags: php, soap, header, xml-namespaces

I'm having some problems by making my SOAP headers:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="elementos" xmlns:ns2="elementoscomunes">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:CABECERA>
            <item>
                <key>Element</key>
                <value>
                    <item>
                        <key>Key</key>
                        <value/>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <key>Values</key>
                        <value>
                            <item>
                                <key>Value</key>
                                <value/>
                            </item>
                        </value>
                    </item>
                </value>
            </item>
        </ns2:CABECERA>
```

So, **ITEM** tags are added because the namespace must not be found, i've tried to change the namespace root, but i think this is not the solution..

My service is under ssl, does all namespaces must be under ssl?

Can the  tag be the error code explanation?

**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: SoapClient::__doRequest(): SSL: Connection reset by peer**

AND

THE SOAP FAULT:

**SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => Error Fetching http headers**

My original .wdsl has the next header definition:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:elem="elementoscomunes" xmlns:elem1="elementos">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <elem:CABECERA>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <Element>
            <Key>?</Key>
            <Values>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <Value>?</Value>
            </Values>
         </Element>
      </elem:CABECERA>
   </soapenv:Header>
      </elem:CABECERA>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

Does i have to add a new namespace?

I'm on an Apache Server so key tag must be "Key" i generate the code as shown below:

```
$headerbody = array('Element' => array('Key' => '', 'Values' => array('Value' => '')));



        $header = new SOAPHeader('namespace', 'CABECERA', $headerbody );
        $sClient->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks you!

Comment: I think maybe is a problem with php SOAP and multiple namespaces working..

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too old, but my solution to do this was:

just replace this:

```
$headerbody = array('Element' => array('Key' => '', 'Values' => array('Value' => '')));
```

with this:

```
$headerbody = (object) array('Element' => array('Key' => '', 'Values' => array('Value' => '')));
```

Hope this help.!

Answer (score 0):

When using php soap client sending data to the header or the body will result in the addition of **item** tags if the data is an array.

i.e.

```
$this->header(NAMESPACE, 'abc', [
        'animal' => 'dog,
    ]);
```

becomes

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:abc>
        <item>
            <key>animal</key>
            <value>dog</value>
        </item>
    </ns1:abc>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Sending an object

```
$this->header(NAMESPACE, 'abc', (object)[
        'animal' => 'dog,
    ]);
```

becomes

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:abc>
        <animal>dog</animal>
    </ns1:abc>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```